# How to run script inside of current command prompt window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

On my Windows 10 machine, if I run a Python script from a command prompt with the following command:

```
c:\Temp>python HelloWorld.py
```

It pops up a new window, displays the script output and quickly closes:

[image]

If I run the cmd prompt "as administrator", it displays the script output in the command prompt window:

[image]

I do not want to put an `input()` statement in my script or run Python with the `-i` flag. There has to be something set differently between administrator mode and user mode.

This worked fine when I had Python 2.7 installed.

My `PATH` environment variable value is the same in user mode and administrator mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `python.exe` running in administrator mode? If the rest of your path settings are correct, then this would probably result in opening in a new "administrator cmd window" as you describe.

You can check this by locating your python 3.x exe as described in your path:
`right clicking it > properties > compatibility > uncheck "Run this program as administrator" > also click "Change Settings for all users" > and once again uncheck "Run this program as administrator"`

Comment: "Run this program as an administrator" is not selected for my user or all users